# robot framework run from Jenkins using git repository

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I need to run my robot framework test cases from Jenkins. I have few questions

1. How to identify whether do I need to use windows or Shell (based on which machine Jenkins are running?)
2. I tried in both ways (windows and shell) but its failing. Below is the commands I used to run
   robot -i [tag] file1.robot

Is there any other commands I need to add?

Please suggest how to run?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: For Shell I am getting below error

tmp/jenkins7409651443396914238.sh: 2: Robot: not found

Comment: For Windows batch command  getting below err msg:

java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Automated Tests/FDR_Regression"): error=2, No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

1. to your first point it depends on the node/agent you define in your
   project, rather than on the machine Jenkins is running on, but i
   suspect that it is the same thing in this case.
2. You also have to have other dependencies on this node/agent, such as robot etc.